# How to reset imageview to same position when swipe android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

In continuation of my previous post [How to use long press in android custom imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245690/how-to-use-long-press-in-android-custom-imageview/)

I need to reset imageview to normal position when i swipe the images after zoom. when I zoom the image and then swipe another image and comes to previous image, it's not changing. It still be in same zoom position.

**In custom ImageView:**

```
float saveScale = 1f;

public void  resetZoom() {
    matrix = new Matrix();
    saveScale = 1f;
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    invalidate();
}
```

**In view pager:**

```
private TouchImageView touchImageView;

pagerSelector.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        if (swipServiceStatus) {                            
            swipServiceStatus=false;
        } else {
            if (pager != null) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(position);
                touchImageView.resetZoom(); // used to reset..but that doesn't do any changes
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First apply scale to the matrix, then apply the matrix to the image:

```
matrix.setScale(1f, 1f);
setImageMatrix(matrix);
```